# Performance of Bentley-Ottman versus naive cross-product intersections for very dense 2D segment distribution

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, computational-geometry

The problem I'm trying to solve is finding all the intersections between line segments which span a given rectangle. The lines are randomly generated up to a given quantity, on the order of 1E3-1E4, and all the endpoints can be found on the rectangle. It's basically the rectangular case of generating random chords in a circle. At low densities the system [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUNBu.png).

The output I'm mainly interested in is the graph generated from the lines and intersections, preferably in a form which I could feed to matplotlib from a .csv file.

To get a sense of dimensions, I first went for a naive implementation, checking each pair for intersects using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) with Numpy. It works relatively ok, but, probably because I didn't pay any attention whatsoever to memory management, it freezes at large numbers of lines.

I have now been trying for a few days to adapt my extremely messy code to use the Bentley-Ottman line sweep algorithm, but I got to a point where I realised I needed to rewrite it from scratch in order to work, mainly because I've been mixing lists with Numpy arrays and explicit indices instead of proper data structures.

My question is, in this particular case of very dense, very long segments, is a line sweep algorithm necessarily faster than the naive approach, and by what margin?

Comment: If you edit your question you are more likely to get help. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The classical sweep line algorithm runs in O(n log n + k) time within O(n) space where n is the number of segments and k is the number of intersections. Clearly k is in O(n^2). A brute force approach (I guess that could be your "naive" approach) takes O(n^2) time and space.

If you know you have short segments sparsely distributed in the plane k might be small, then the sweep line is faster. From the space aspect it depends on what you do with the output. If you store all intersection points then you need the O(n^2) space also with the sweep line.